# SVN property changes to unrelated files

Tags: svn

Many times after I have committed changes to svn, I find many property changes to completely unrelated files and directories. Why does this happen, and is it necessary to commit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens sometimes when you do a merge from another branch into your working copy. SVN has a tendency to "over-store" information about merges.

Comment: Should I ignore them and make a revert, or is it better to commit them?

Comment: What I usually do is to verify them manually and if they do not contain any actual modification on the code then I revert them. But it does not do any harm to commit them either.